# My React Router doesn't work for all routes

Tags: reactjs, routes

I am new to React. I am having a problem with my code below as only Dashboard and Register routes show up. Login shows blank page. I have tried creating other routes and they don't work either. Only routes specifically called Dashboard and Register work. Anyone has any idea where the problem is? Thanks in advance!

**App.js**

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard.jsx'
import Login from './pages/Login.jsx'
import Register from './pages/Register.jsx'


function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <div className="container">
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Dashboard />}/>
            <Route path='/register' element={<Register />}/>
            <Route path='/login' element={<Login />}/>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**pages/Dashboard.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'

function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <div>Dashboard</div>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```

**pages/Register.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'

function Register() {
  return (
    <div>Register</div>
  )
}

export default Register
```

**pages/Login.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'

function Login() {
  return (
    <div>Login</div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Comment: what happens when you change the route of "/login" to other route that works? and changing the one that works to "/login"

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro thanks for your reply. the text just dissapear and re appear. Nothing abnormal. This is so weird.

Comment: end your application and restart it

Comment: Tried setting up a app using your code and it works as expected. https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-brattain-htj4px?file=/src/App.js

Comment: you can also add exact so that it render only one component

Comment: Thanks everyone. I found the cause. It was due to VS code's compiling. I restarted VS code and the error was fixed!

Answer (score 0):

add exact in front of the path, check https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start for more info

```
    function App() {
      return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <div className="container">
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path='/' component={<Dashboard />}/>
            <Route exact path='/register' component={<Register />}/>
            <Route exact path='/login' component={<Login />}/>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace component by element. like this,

```
<Routes>
            <Route
              path="/"
              element={<ListEmployeeComponent></ListEmployeeComponent>}
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/employees"
              element={<ListEmployeeComponent />}
            />
          </Routes>
```